# Need to mass delete users

Tags: users, 6

I want to start by saying this is my first dealings with drupal of any kind. I can turn a wordpress site inside and out but have zero experience with drupal.

My company has recently inherited a Drupal 6.25 site from a company we purchased. I need to delete a lot of inactive users ( 6+ years inactive). I have found how to do that in the administer>user management, deleteing 25 at a time. However, this site has not really been maintained and there are 1,428 pages of users. Yes, 1,428 pages .

I've tried to find a module but everything I can find is for V. 7 and newer. Can anyone give me any advice on where to begin to clean this up?

I've seen mention of cron jobs but have no idead how to go about that for 6.25. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Views + Views Bulk Operations, configure the VBO to run on batch processing.

Comment: Drupal 6 is no longer supported. See [Drupal 6 end-of-life announcement](https://www.drupal.org/forum/general/news-and-announcements/2015-11-09/drupal-6-end-of-life-announcement) which means your D6 site has security holes. Might as well "delete" these users when you migrate to D7 or D8.

Comment: Another option: inside the user list view, modify the pager so that each page shows 500 users or any number you want.